# How to handle null value in JSON in SWIFT

Tags: json, swift

I have a problem with JSON decoding. I have **UpdateNickname** and **UpdateNicknameMessage** structs and variable **Message** inside **UpdateNickname** could be a null. I got an error whenever it is a null. I want to handle this problem. Here is my struct:

```
struct UpdateNicknameMessage: Codable {
 let id: Int
 let nickname: String
 let email: String 
}

struct UpdateNickname: Codable {
 var Status: Int
 var Result: String
 var Message: UpdateNicknameMessage

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case Status = "Status"
    case Result = "Result"
    case Message = "Message"
}

init?(from jsonObject: AnyObject) {
    guard let Status1: Int = jsonObject.object(forKey: "Status") as? Int,
        let Result1: String = jsonObject.object(forKey: "Result") as? String,
        let Message1: UpdateNicknameMessage = jsonObject.object(forKey: "Message") as? UpdateNicknameMessage
        else { return nil }

    Status = Status1
    Result = Result1
    Message = Message1
  }
}
```

and JSON looks like this:

```
{"Message": {
    email = "123@123.com";
    id = 56;
    nickname = testNickname;
}, 
 "Status": 200, 
 "Result": success}
```

And this is my code for decoding JSON in swift. I use try catch to handle my error.

```
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            do {
                let model = try decoder.decode(UpdateNickname.self, from: data)
                let serverStatus = model.Status

                if serverStatus == 200 {
                     //EVERYTHING IS FINE
                } else {
                     //server not working
                }
            } catch {
               //cant convert JSON into struct
               print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
```

so my variable **Message** can return null if something goes wrong with the server.

```
{"Message": null, 
 "Status": 400, 
 "Result": problem}
```

When i try to decode JSON when **Message** is null i get an error

> **The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.**

How can i fix this problem and handle null value?

Comment: This is because your `JSON`format is invalid

Comment: so it should return empty { } instead of null?

Comment: Try to update your `JSON` as the following: 
```
{
 "Message": {
  "email": "123@123.com",
  "id": 56,
  "nickname": "testNickname"
 },
 "Status": 200,
 "Result": "success"
}
```

Comment: `<null>` != `null`

Comment: I did a misstype , it should be null instead of <null>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
var Message: UpdateNicknameMessage
```

to this one:

```
var Message: UpdateNicknameMessage?
```

Everything will work fine now.

Comment: Simple fix , i like this! I completly forgot about optional value, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle it making as `optional`. Please refer below model class.

```
struct UpdateNicknameMessage : Codable {
    let email : String?
    let id : Int?
    let nickname : String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case email = "email"
        case id = "id"
        case nickname = "nickname"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        email = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .email)
        id = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        nickname = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .nickname)
    }

}


struct UpdateNickname : Codable {
    let message : UpdateNicknameMessage?
    let status : Int?
    let result : String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case message = "Message"
        case status = "Status"
        case result = "Result"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        message = try values.decodeIfPresent(Message.self, forKey: .Message)
        status = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .Status)
        result = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .Result)
    }

}
```

I suggest to use [json4swift](http://www.json4swift.com/) to create model class from JSON response.

**Update:**

I think you need to more clear about the usage codable protocol first. Consider, Your server is giving `Internal server error` due to any XYZ reason. I think your approach is not worked for it.

I am sure it will give a same error.

> The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.

So my first question is

**How you could manage in such type of situation?**

That's it from my end!!

Happy codding!!

Comment: Only message is optional value ( so i dont need others to be optional too) , but your code should also works.

Answer (score 0):

Set all your variables in Structs as optionals.

***EX:***

````
var Status: Int?
 var Result: String?
 var Message: UpdateNicknameMessage? ```
````

Comment: Only message is optional so i dont need others to be optional too. Simple var message: updatenicknamemessage? will work.